# Internet Explorer problem with long file names in input type=file

Tags: internet-explorer, file-upload, internet-explorer-8, input-type-file

My QA tester is running long filename use cases through our application and ran into unexpected behavior in Internet Explorer 8 (shocking, I know...).

The filename including path is 258 characters long. In Firefox/Chrom/Safari, the filepath and/or name displays as expected. In IE, the filepath/name doesn't display at all.

I've been googling all morning and haven't found anything close to related to this issue. If we go over 260 characters, we get IE's invalid file name error.

I'd post code, but at this point it's an HTML input issue, so the code is:

```
<input type="file" name="myUploadField" />
```